# JQuery Validate input file type

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that can have 0-hundreds of `<input type="file">` elements. I have named them sequentially depending on how many are dynamically added to the page.

For example:

```
<input type="file" required="" name="fileupload1" id="fileupload1">
<input type="file" required="" name="fileupload2" id="fileupload2">
<input type="file" required="" name="fileupload3" id="fileupload3">
<input type="file" required="" name="fileupload999" id="fileupload999">
```

In my JQuery I want to validate these inputs on acceptable MIME/file type. Like this:

```
$("#formNew").validate({
    rules: {
        fileupload: {
            required: true, 
            accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg"
        }
    }
```

Immediately my problem is that the `name` attribute of the input file elements is dynamic. It has to be dynamic so that my web application can deal with each upload correctly. So obviously using "fileupload" isn't going to work in the rules section.

How do I set the rules for all inputs which have a name like "fileupload"?

This is the code that dynamically adds the inputs:

```
var filenumber = 1;
$("#AddFile").click(function () { //User clicks button #AddFile
    $('<li><input type="file" name="FileUpload' + filenumber + '" id="FileUpload' + filenumber + '" required=""/> <a href="#" class="RemoveFileUpload">Remove</a></li>').prependTo("#FileUploader");
    filenumber++;
    return false;
});
$("#FileUploader").on('click', '.RemoveFileUpload', function () { //Remove input
    if (filenumber > 0) {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        filenumber--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One the elements are added, use the rules method to add the rules

```
//bug fixed thanks to @Sparky
$('input[name^="fileupload"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg"
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8dAU8/)

---

Update

```
var filenumber = 1;
$("#AddFile").click(function () { //User clicks button #AddFile
    var $li = $('<li><input type="file" name="FileUpload' + filenumber + '" id="FileUpload' + filenumber + '" required=""/> <a href="#" class="RemoveFileUpload">Remove</a></li>').prependTo("#FileUploader");

    $('#FileUpload' + filenumber).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg"
    })

    filenumber++;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun really great. But the elements are added/removed dynamically whenever the user presses a button. There could be none, or 1, or whatever. When/where would I add the to the rules method? I tried adding it within the form submit event but its not working.

Comment: @volumeone can you share the code which is adding the element

Comment: done please see edit. I was thinking that when I click on the form submit button, it should check whether a "name^=fileupload" input exists and then run the add rule method before somehow the validation kicks in. So far its not worked but do you think I'm thinking correctly?

Comment: Arun, when you use a jquery selector that targets more than one element, you **must** use an `each()` to apply a jQuery validate method like `rules()`.  Your fiddle only works because the elements also have the `required` attribute.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/8dAU8/2/

Comment: @Sparky then it will be a buggy implementation of the plugin method right... probably we need to apply a patch... by design a plugin need to apply to all the elements in the called element set

Comment: Arun, it's a known condition.  Maybe you should post a bug report to the jQuery Validate developer at GitHub... the methods for this plugin have always required containment within an `.each()` when targeting more than one:  http://jsfiddle.net/8dAU8/3  ~  meanwhile, you should fix or delete the first half of your answer.

Comment: [As per documentation for `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules):  _"Adds the specified rules and returns all rules for the **first matched** element."_  ~ Also see [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/570).

Comment: @ArunPJohny what is the need for the "var $li =" part in the third line? Why store this in a variable?

Comment: @volumeone, minor details aside, the _only relevant point_ here is that you use `.rules('add')` _within_ your `click` handler _immediately after creating the element_.  That's essentially the whole answer.

Comment: Arun and @volumeone, you don't need the `required=""` attribute within your `input` element when you're declaring the `required` rule elsewhere.  Otherwise, if you _think_ you need that HTML5 attribute, then at least use it correctly:  `required="required"`

Comment: @Sparky when I use JQuery to add `.prop(required, true)` it adds it as `required=""` not as `required="required"`.

Do I add the `.each(function () { $(this).rules('add'... ` bit immediately after creating the element? Or the just `$('#FileUpload' + filenumber).rules('add'...`

Comment: @volumeone, jQuery changes the DOM, not your HTML markup... two different things.  IMO, `required="required"` is best, but why do you need it at all?  You're already declaring the `required` rule elsewhere.  If you're only attaching `.rules()` to one element, then you wouldn't need the `.each()`, and use `rules()` _anytime_ after the element has been created.

Comment: how to check the filesize?

Answer (score 3):

So, I had the same issue and sadly just adding to the rules didn't work. I found out that accept: and extension: are not part of JQuery validate.js by default and it requires an additional-Methods.js plugin to make it work.

So for anyone else who followed this thread and it still didn't work, you can try adding [additional-Methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js) to your  tag in addition to the answer above and it should work.

Comment: Been scratching my head trying to get file validation to work, thank you for this answer!

Comment: I may be wrong but as of today (12/3/21) it seems like you don't need that extra "additional-methods.js" file. At least not in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) immediately after creating the element...

```
var filenumber = 1;
$("#AddFile").click(function () { //User clicks button #AddFile

    // create the new input element
    $('<li><input type="file" name="FileUpload' + filenumber + '" id="FileUpload' + filenumber + '" /> <a href="#" class="RemoveFileUpload">Remove</a></li>').prependTo("#FileUploader");

    // declare the rule on this newly created input field        
    $('#FileUpload' + filenumber).rules('add', {
        required: true,  // <- with this you would not need 'required' attribute on input
        accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg"
    });

    filenumber++; // increment counter for next time

    return false;
});
```

- You'll still need to use `.validate()` to initialize the plugin within a DOM ready handler.
- You'll still need to declare rules for your static elements using `.validate()`.   Whatever input elements that are part of the form when the page loads... declare their rules within `.validate()`.
- You don't need to use `.each()`, when you're only targeting ONE element with the jQuery selector attached to `.rules()`.
- You don't need the `required` attribute on your input element when you're declaring the `required` rule using `.validate()` or `.rules('add')`.  For whatever reason, if you still want the HTML5 attribute, at least use a proper format like `required="required"`.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/8dAU8/5/**

Comment: I've tried this and Firebug is showing an error of "TypeError: s is undefined" and the form breaks so the submit button doesn't work. No error is showing on the webpage itself.

Comment: i updated jsfiddle so you can see the issue http://jsfiddle.net/8dAU8/4/
 Try adding a txt or zip file and it doesn't show any error.

Comment: @volumeone, my mistake.  You cannot increment counter until after the rule is declared.  Take note that I removed a bunch of superfluous code.... see: http://jsfiddle.net/8dAU8/5/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky - So I notice that the validation does not updated on change of adding a file... It updates if the input is activated again or if the submit button is clicked. Is there a way to update the validation message on change to not be in an error state?

Comment: @isaacweathers, you would manually call the `.valid()` method when you need to trigger a new validation test.