# How to distinguish each file_upload control by id in RoR

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my application I am generating multiple `file_upload` control using loop i.e below:

```
<div class='row' id='selfintroduction'>
    <% @sections.each do |s| %>
        <span class='label' style="font-size:small;font-weight:bold">
            <%= s.SectionName %>
        </span>
        <br/>
        <span class='formw' style="font-size:small">
            <input type='file' id='Self' name='Self'/> // File upload  control
        </span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

In the `@sections` loop I have `SectionName` and I am generating `file_upload` control along with each `SectionName`. And I want to apply `file_type` validation on the `file_upload` control in the `onchange` method using jQuery, but the problem is that multiple `file_upload` control have the same id i.e

```
<input type='file' id='Self' name='Self'/>
```

Then I have attached `SectionName` along with `file_upload` control `id` i.e

```
<input type='file' id='Self[<%= s.SectionName %>]'
```

below is the `onchange` method where I get `file_upload` control value using `id`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        $("#Self["+ i +"]").on('change',function() {
            alert("Self["+ i +"]");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But in the above `onchange` method I am unable to get `file_upload` control `id` with `SectionName` to distinguish each `file_upload` control. How can I do this?

Kindly suggest me, Waiting for reply.
Thanks

Comment: Why you are not using a class?

Comment: How I use class here, kindly explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='Self' class="inputfileupload" name='Self'/>
```

JQUERY:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $( ".inputfileupload" ).change(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));

        var url = this.value;
        var ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        if (input.files && input.files[0]&& (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg")) {

           alert("Valid image");
        }else{
           alert("Image format not valid");
        }
      });

    });
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929355/jquery-validate-input-file-type) stack to validate multiple file uploads(you can use jquery validate).

Comment: using your code I am getting the id of the `file_upload` control but also I want to get `file_upload` value through this id. kindly suggest me

Comment: Check the updated code to validate the file if it is an image or not.