# Allowed extension phpmailer

Tags: php, upload, phpmailer

how could i change my code to only accept some extensions.

look my code :

```
  <?php
    ob_start();
   $_SESSION['nomecomp'] = $_POST['nomecomp'];

       $email_env = $_POST['email_env'];
      if (isset($email_env)) {
   //variaveis vindas da pagina
    $varcritico = $_POST['varcritico'];
    $nomecomp = $_POST['nomecomp'];
    $chapa = $_POST['chapa'];
   $funcao = $_POST['funcao'];
      $setor = $_POST['setor'];
      $unidade = $_POST['unidade'];
      $deschelp = $_POST['deschelp'];





     //variveis do modal
     //$email_env = $_POST['email_env'];
      //$senha_env = $_POST['senha_env'];






       <td>$deschelp</td>



        </tr>
       </table>'";

        /**
       * PHPMailer multiple files upload and send example
           */

        $msg = '';
           //if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {

         // Create a message
       // This should be somewhere in your include_path
          include ("lib/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
```

i have tried add some codes , but dont made sucess , for example , could i try push the array and see if the extension are inside some array ?

thanks.

Comment: First, build an array of allowed extensions ($AllowedFileTypes). Second, get the extension of the uploaded file ($FileExtension) and then check to see if extension is in_array($FileExtension, $AllowedFileType)

Comment: like this : `$allowed = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'rtf', 'txt','zip');`

Comment: Yeah, something to that effect. Then either validate the form before submitting or validate the file type/extension before copying/moving from the tmp localtion

Comment: could u give a example ?

Comment: Answer/example offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want to check the uploaded file types before moving them:

```
$AllowedFileTypes = array("pdf","txt"); // build array
$FileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // get filename of file input
$FileType = end((explode(".", $FileName))); // get file type/extension
if(in_array($FileType, $AllowedFileTypes)){ // check to see if file type is allowed
 // perform copy/move file
}
else{
 // ignore/alert/whatever
}
```

Note: You may have to amend the variables to suit your requirements.

If you wish to validate the file type/extension before submitting the form, take a look at jQuery validation for file input: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929391/715105