# show filename of attachment(s) in email body phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I have a form on my website using phpmailer and just added attachment feature into it and works perfect and I receive the form and the attachments in the email but is there a way to show the filename(s) of the attachments in the email body content, below is my current code

```
<?php

// PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
// Base files 
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {

// create object of PHPMailer class with boolean parameter which sets/unsets exception.
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
//$mail->isSMTP(); // using SMTP protocol
$mail->Host = 'emailhost'; // SMTP host
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // enable smtp authentication
$mail->Username = 'emailaddress';  // sender host              
$mail->Password = 'emailpassword'; // sender host password                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // for encrypted connection                           
$mail->Port = 587;   // port for SMTP     

$mail->setFrom('emailaddress', "Name"); // sender's email and name
$mail->addAddress('emailaddress', "Name");  // receiver's email and name

$attachmentNames = [];

for ($ct = 0, $ctMax = count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct < $ctMax; $ct++) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];        
    $FileType = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');
    if(in_array($FileType, $allowTypes)){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        if ($mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename)) {
        $attachmentNames[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to attach file ' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Sorry only jpg, png and jpeg files are allowed to upload';
    }
}

$mail->Subject = 'New Repair Booking';

$mail->Body    = "A new repair has been booked in. The repair information is below" . "\r\n\r\n" . "Repair Date: " . $_POST["date"] . "\r\n" . "Device: " . $_POST["selectdevice"] . "\r\n" . "Brand: " . $_POST["selectbrand"] . "\r\n" . "Name: " . $_POST["name"] . "\r\n" . "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" . "Phone Number: " . $_POST["phone"] . "\r\n" . "Repair Description/Issue: " . $_POST["repairdescription"] . "\r\n\r\n" . "Attached Filename(s): " . implode(', ', $attachmentNames);
}
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of filenames as you parse the attachments, then `implode` and append that to `Body`:

```php
$attachmentNames = [];
//...
for ($ct = 0, $ctMax = count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct < $ctMax; $ct++) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        if ($mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename)) {
            $attachmentNames[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to attach file ' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
//...
if (count($attachmentNames) > 0) {
    $mail->Body .= "\n\nAttachments: " . implode(', ', $attachmentNames);
}
```

Note that your file upload handling is not safe because you are not validating them with `is_uploaded_file` or `move_uploaded_file`. See [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and [the PHPMailer file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) for how to do this properly. You should also check the return value of `addAttachment()` as it's possible for that to fail too.

Comment: Thank you, I have amended the code to be safer and done the filenames within the email content, I have amended the original code with the new changes

Comment: I'm still new to using phpmailer, how do I check the return value of the addAttachment and also how do I only allow certain file extensions to be attached such as jpg and png?

Comment: Check the return value just like you're doing for `move_uploaded_file`: `if (!$mail->addAttachment(...) { $msg .= 'Failed to attach file...`. To filter extensions, use [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo) to break up the filename, then check the extension against an allow list. Bear in mind that checking file extensions isn't sufficient to be sure that files are the type they say they are, though it's a good start!

Comment: Just tested it again and works fine if attachments are added but if the user does not add any attachments, I get Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Message body empty

Comment: Check your logic! If you *require* attachments, don't try to send if there are none. Alternatively, make sure you're not setting your message body inside the attachment checks.

Comment: This is where it's getting me confused as unsure what code to alter so that attachments are optional. I done this for the return value but unsure if it's right `if (!$mail->addAttachment {
            $msg .= 'Failed to attach file';
        }`

I added that in after

`} else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }`

Comment: That looks about right – but this is everyday programming, nothing specific to PHPMailer. Check what happens in every possible combination of outcomes and make sure you've got them all covered. This is where consistent coding style and IDEs with built-in static analysis (like PHPStorm and VS Code) can really help.

Comment: It don't seem to work with the code, I either get unexpected ; or unexpected } with the code `if (!$mail->addAttachment {             $msg .= 'Failed to attach file';         }`. Tried removing ; and } and that's what caused the other unexpected error

Comment: I have managed to get it working so far if attachments are attached or not, I have updated the original code to what I have currently, it's just the return bit I am struggling with

Comment: Eep, no. Look at what you're doing – you're attaching each file twice. I don't know what you mean by "the return bit", but you'll end up with an empty body again if there are no attachments.

Comment: It seems to be working though if I don't attach a attachment and sends the form all ok and works all ok if I do attach attachments, I don't get the empty body message like before. I do get a error log that says PHP Warning:  file_exists() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given. How should the code be as getting confused on it now

Comment: Altered the code

`for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            if(isset($uploadfile))
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
            $attachmentNames[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }`

Comment: That code I just put in the above comment does work and not getting any errors in the error log

Comment: Why are you calling `isset`? The second call to `addAttachment` is silently failing because you moved the file it refers to. I will update my answer with further code.

Comment: To be honest, I have been Googling the code and seeing what works as new to phpmailer and when used isset code and got no errors and the form sent with and without attachments I thought it was working all ok

Comment: I have updated the code to yours Synchro and it's working and will update my original post with the updated code, only thing I didn't do is was the `if count($attachmentNames) > 0) {` line as that caused the message body empty message and need the attachments as optional rather than required, will be ok like that won't it?

Comment: I thought I would try and add in file extension code so only allow jpg and png file extensions but getting errors PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
PHP Warning:  end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

I got the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244570/allowed-extension-phpmailer

I have updated the code in the original post with the file extension code added, not sure where to put it, just tried to fit it in where I thought it goes

Comment: It's because that's bad code and will break if there is no extension. Use [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/pathinfo) as I suggested earlier: `$FileType = pathinfo($FileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Sorry don't understand it how the allowed filetype can only be jpg or png with that code, I found this example

`$fname = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$this->ext = pathinfo($fname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//I assume you've done the if move_upload thing to get the file to its destination
$this->filename = $name.'-'.date('dmY-Hi').'-cv.'.$this->ext;
$mail->AddAttachment('files/cvs/'.$this->filename, "CV File");`

But still don't get how that will know to be only jpg or png when altering it, where does the file extension jpg, png go so that's the only file extensions that can be uploaded

Comment: I have updated the code in my original post to include another bit of filetype code using pathinfo, it works sending the email with and without attachments with no errors but does not say the message about only uploading jpg or png files if I upload a xls file for example, the email does work though if I do upload the wrong file and I receive the email but don't attach the wrong file type attachment but if I attach the correct file types, it sends the email with the attachments

Comment: That line just fixed the bug in the code you linked to – all you had to do was replace that one line and it would work. You seem to be pasting random bits of code together and hoping it works - that's not programming! Read what it's doing, apply some logic; I'm not here to do your thinking for you.

Comment: Sorry but unsure what one line I would of needed to change if the code is almost correct in my original post with the updated code?